# Paste or Insert images that are hyperlinked to a URL with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

In Outlook or other email apps you can put an image in your email message > right-click > link > and link it to some webpage. I have to do this daily and would love to automate this. I've worked with WinClip and WinClipAPI to paste linked text. Reaching out to anyone who has got these classes to work for pasting images linked in this way.

Here's my guess/start to how I would go about this with winclip/winclipapi. I'd probably have to use some other function other than "SetHTML" but not sure what.

```
^+v::

text1 := "<a href=" 
text2 := """"
text3 := "https://MyUrlGoesHere/"
text4 := """"
text5 := ">"
text6 := "how would I get the image to go here?"
text7 := "</a>"
fullStr := text1 . text2 . text3 . text4 . text5 . text6 . text7
WinClip.Clear()
WinClip.SetHTML(fullStr)
WinClip.Paste()


#Include C:\path\AHK\Libraries\WinClipAPI.ahk
#Include C:\path\AHK\Libraries\WinClip.ahk
```

Comment: Do you have the images as image files, or are the hosted somewhere and you have urls for them? If as files, I don't think this is possible, at least with one command. Could run two, first paste in the image and then hyperlink it.

Comment: I have access to both. If I get it from a webpage then I would have to resize it, but that is maybe the least of my worries.